# Backbone.js DOM events full list

Tags: events, dom, backbone.js

Anyone knows where I could find a complete list of built-in DOM events in Backbone.js? I managed to guess some fancy ones like "mouseout", but just a complete list would be very helpful. Not available in official docs or google.

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Backbone's DOM event for Views (which is what I'm assuming you're talking about) come from jQuery or ZeptoJS (whichever one you are using). Any valid event from either of those libraries, is a valid event in a Backbone view.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

http://zeptojs.com/